# unable to build pipeline no element decodebin[Gstreamer]

Tags: java, c, gstreamer, pipeline

[Android.mk]

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := tutorial-3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := tutorial-3.c dummy.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := gstreamer_android
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

ifndef GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID
$(error GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID is not defined!)
endif

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/arm
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/armv7
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),arm64-v8a)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/arm64
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/x86
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86_64)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/x86_64
else
$(error Target arch ABI not supported: $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI))
endif

GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH  := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT)/share/gst-android/ndk-build/
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/plugins.mk
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS         := $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CORE) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_SYS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_EFFECTS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_PLAYBACK)
G_IO_MODULES              := gnutls
GSTREAMER_EXTRA_DEPS      := gstreamer-video-1.0 gobject-2.0
GSTREAMER_EXTRA_LIBS      := -liconv
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/gstreamer-1.0.mk
```

[Pipeline]

```
data->pipeline =
      gst_parse_launch ("tcpclientsrc host=10.42.0.1 port=7001 ! avdec_h264 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false ", &error);
  if (error) {
    gchar *message =
        g_strdup_printf ("Unable to build pipeline: %s", error->message);
    g_clear_error (&error);
    set_ui_message (message, data);
    g_free (message);
    return NULL;
  }
```

My app runs succesfully but app shows message(`"unable to build pipeline no element decodebin"`)
I want to realtime video streamin on wifi host and port with pi, 
Please Help me guys.

Comment: which codes ? @lennon310